# To repair bicycle is his job. Vs. Repairing bicycle is his job

Tags: infinitives, gerunds, subjects

My question is what the differences are between the two sentences. In what situation do you use infinitive as a subject? And when do you use gerund as a subjective? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Neither sounds particularly English to me, as *bicycle* is not a mass noun.

Comment: "His job is repairing bicycles".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> John's job is repairing bicycles.

If this is what John does for eight hours every day, you want to use the gerund.

> John's job is to repair the bicycle.

If somebody is assigning tasks, and John's assignment of repairing a bicycle is only going to happen once, you would be more likely to use the infinitive.

Both of these sentences can be inverted (although this wouldn't be the usual order), and they have the same difference in meaning.

Comment: I appreciate your telling me the answer. Thank a lot!